# C reverse string with dynamic memory

Tags: c, string, function, pointers, memory-leaks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* ch_reversed(const char* const str);
size_t ch_length(const char* const str);

int main()
{
    char* str = "merhaba";
    
    printf("%s", ch_reversed(str));
    
    return 0;
}

char* ch_reversed(const char* const str)
{
    if (!ch_length(str))
        return NULL;

    char* temp = malloc(ch_length(str) + 1);
    size_t length = ch_length(str);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
        temp[i] = str[length - i - 1];

    temp[length] = '\0';

    return temp;
}

size_t ch_length(const char* const str)
{
    size_t length = 0;

    while (str[length++]) {}
    
    return length - 1;
}
```

- In that code, i allocated memory for reversing the string and in the main function i am directly passing the `ch_reversed` function to `printf`. But does that cause a memory leak since i can not free the memory with this type of usage? If so i can assign return value to a variable and use the variable and free the memory with it but i don't want to. I want to be able to use the function directly as i did here. So what should i do?
- Also is it appropriate to pass the string as `const char* const` for this case since i am not altering the parameter in anyway? Or should i pass it as `const char*` or another way?
- Last thing, is there any bad written part that should be changed?

Comment: Yes, you have a leak — you have to capture the return value from `ch_reversed()` and free it before exiting to avoid the leak.  The alternative is accepting the leak, or passing a pre-allocated buffer (and its length) to the function (as well as the string to be reversed).  Either `const char *` or `const char * const` is OK; using just `const char *` is more usual as it doesn't matter whether the pointer itself is changed — it's just a copy of a variable from the `main()` program (calling function).  What you've written is OK.

Comment: The empty string isn't being handled correctly.  In that case, it should return an empty string, i.e. a pointer to a null character.  Instead, it returns a `NULL` pointer.  You should be able to print an empty string, but trying to print a `NULL` pointer will cause a seg fault.  There is no need to make a special case of the empty string at all.  Just delete that entire check and (1) you'll fix the bug and (2) your code will be smaller.

Comment: Also, the `const char* const str` declarations don't really make sense.  They should be `const char *str`.  The point is that the target of the pointer is constant.  Nobody cares about the pointer itself.  Look at the man page for things like `strcpy` for example, and see how they declare their string arguments.

Comment: Incidentally, calling `ch_length()` three times for a given non-empty string seems excessive — once is enough.  Save the length from the first (only) call and use it in subsequent lines.  Given your copious use of `const` elsewhere, it is surprising that you did not use `const` in `char* str = "merhaba";`.

Comment: Incidentally, what reason is there to use your own implementation of strlen() ? I’ve used C implementations where strlen is highly optimised and runs many times faster than naive code, for example by checking 8 or 16 bytes for nul characters at the same time.

Comment: @gnasher729 I am preparing for Ecole 42 school and i heard that they want you to be able to write your own implementations of some C functions if i am not mistaken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But does that cause a memory leak since i can not free the memory with
> this type of usage?

[Valgrind](https://www.valgrind.org/) is a nice tool to check for memory errors. I ran your code through valgrind, and here is the result:

```
==174== HEAP SUMMARY:
==174==     in use at exit: 8 bytes in 1 blocks
==174==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 1 frees, 520 bytes allocated
==174==
==174== 8 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==174==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==174==    by 0x1091E6: ch_reversed (main.c:22)
==174==    by 0x10918B: main (main.c:11)
==174==
==174== LEAK SUMMARY:
==174==    definitely lost: 8 bytes in 1 blocks
==174==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==174==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==174==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==174==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==174==
```

So yea, you are definitely leaking memory. There is no way to actually NOT leak memory the way you call the function. You don't assign the result to any variable therefore, you can not `free()`. I don't see why you don't want to just assign the result and call `free()` later.

> I want to be able to use the function directly as i did here. So what
> should i do?

You can call it immediately and just pass the pointer to `printf()`,

```
int main(void)
{
    char *str = ch_reversed("merhaba");

    printf("%s", str);

    free(str);

    return 0;
}
```

You can of course work with an array instead, and modify it:

```
char* ch_reversed(char* str) /* argument changed, as we want to modify the content of the array */
{
    size_t length = ch_length(str); /* no need for multiple function calls */

    if (!length)
    return NULL;

    char* temp = malloc(length + 1);

    strcpy(temp, str); /* copy original string to temp */ 

    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
      str[i] = temp[length - i - 1];

    free(temp); /* free temp */

    return str;
}
```

your `main()` function should look like this,

```
int main(void)
{
    char str[] = "hello";

    printf("%s", ch_reversed(str)); /* this will alter str though */

    return 0;
}
```

> Is it appropriate to pass the string as const char* const for this
> case since i am not altering the parameter in anyway?

It is legal to do so, if you don't plan to perform any pointer arithmetic - modification or manipulate the string.

> Last thing, is there any bad written part that should be changed?

This question would probably be more suitable for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).